# Drupal 6 CCK date field is saving current time when the time field is left blank

Tags: entities, datetime

I have a node type='event' that has a "text field with date popup calendar".  The date format is "05/13/2015 - 7:02pm".  On the edit page, the form renders as two fields: a calendar popup text field and a separate field for the time.  This field is mandatory; but, it has been requested that the time value not be mandatory.

The problem occurs when the node is saved.  It saves the date correctly; but, it inserts the current time if no time has been entered.   Is there a way to have it not enter a time or just default to midnight if no time has been entered?

Answer (score 0):

Set your **Default value** for your event date field to **Blank**. This will make the date/time field empty upon default. A user has to enter date if it's a required field, but can leave the time field blank. If it's left blank it will default to 00:00.